# Selecting img element with XPath

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I am trying to select `img` element by XPath for odoo.
HTML:

```
<form action="/shop/cart/update" method="post" class="card oe_product_cart" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" data-publish="on">
            <div class="card-body p-1 oe_product_image">
                <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-id="1015" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/form[1]/div[1]/input[1]" value="d85a8885a324296ca8dd6805cc336b6c9d45996bo1588971064"/>
                <div class="ribbon-wrapper" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-id="1015" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]">
                    <a href="#" role="button" class="ribbon btn btn-danger">Sale</a>
                </div>
                <a class="d-block h-100" itemprop="url" href="/shop/product/a4tech-bloody-v8m-2">
                    <span data-oe-model="product.template" data-oe-id="2" data-oe-field="image_1920" data-oe-type="image" data-oe-expression="product.image_1920" class="d-flex h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center"><img src="/web/image/product.template/2/image_256/A4Tech%20Bloody%20V8M?unique=0a360e4" class="img img-fluid" alt="A4Tech Bloody V8M"/></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body p-0 text-center o_wsale_product_information">
                <div class="p-2 o_wsale_product_information_text">
                    <h6 class="o_wsale_products_item_title">
                        <a data-oe-model="product.template" data-oe-id="2" data-oe-field="name" data-oe-type="char" data-oe-expression="product.name" itemprop="name" href="/shop/product/a4tech-bloody-v8m-2" content="A4Tech Bloody V8M">A4Tech Bloody V8M</a>

                    </h6>
                    <div class="product_price" itemprop="offers" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
                        <del data-oe-type="monetary" data-oe-expression="combination_info['list_price']" style="white-space: nowrap;" class="text-danger mr-2 d-none">$ <span class="oe_currency_value">15.00</span></del>
                        <span data-oe-type="monetary" data-oe-expression="combination_info['price']">$ <span class="oe_currency_value">15.00</span></span>
                        <span itemprop="price" style="display:none;">15.0</span>
                        <span itemprop="priceCurrency" style="display:none;">USD</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="o_wsale_product_btn" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-id="1015" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/form[1]/div[2]/div[2]"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

The part I need is near the `<span data-oe-model...` and that image link. I don't understand, how to move forward through the span tag. `span[@data-oe-model = "product.template"]/a[@data-oe-id="2"]/a[@data-oe-field="image_1920"]/a[@data-oe-type="image"]/a[@data-oe-expression="product.image_1920"]/a[@class="d-flex h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center"]`

This does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your (overspecific) XPath-1.0 expression should be

```
//span[@data-oe-model="product.template" and @data-oe-id="2" and @data-oe-field="image_1920" and @data-oe-type="image" and @data-oe-expression="product.image_1920" and @class="d-flex h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center"]
```

This selects the `<span>` element with all of the given properties. But because the `<span>` element if empty, you won't get any result.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
//img[@alt="A4Tech Bloody V8M"]
```

will select all `img` elements with an `alt` attribute value of `"alt="A4Tech Bloody V8M"`.